# How to disable HTML in member bio field

Tags: members, spam

EE sites have been plagued with spam accounts targeting the bio field with html links and bbcode to do the same. Including mine. I am sure one of the 2.x releases disabled html code by default but cannot find it in the change log.

Other than hacking the core, any options to disable this?

Thanks.

Update - found this "Altered member profile fields to disallow HTML." in : http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-1-1

So looks like it was added, but not to the forum member pages perhaps. Classic EL.

Comment: Are you actually using the default member profile templates?

Comment: Actually the forum module is the only place these profile pages are visible. New member registration is turned on, but only the forum based registration page is used.